# SQl server hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website application, In that website i created four text boxes(txtSchoolName,txtBranchName,txtClass,txtSection)....

I want to know about SQL server Hierarcy... and How to create hierarchy sqlserver?
 how to insert values in that? and also how to connect that hierarchy to ASP.net website(C#)?

Anyone pls Tell me about it...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I really hope this isn't your homework... but nevertheless here you go.

What you need to think about is the difference between a hierarchical database structure and a relational database structure. Hierarchical databases are very rigidly structured. This means they can be very fast because the relationships of the data is structured for a very specific method of data retrieval where you know the path to the data you want and your requirements don't change very often. There is a ton of information out there on why hierarchical structure is the way to go in certain projects. (XML database structures are hierarchical, generally speaking).

Relational on the other hand is a bit more general purpose. You don't need to know the specific path to the data because you can use relationships to discover what data is available. It's also easier to add new data structures. Relational databases, when written well, are normalized for just this purpose where as hierarchical database do not have this requirement.

Ok so how to build a hierarchical structure, check out this article:

[High Performance Hierarchies in Sql Server](http://www.yafla.com/papers/sqlhierarchies/sqlhierarchies.htm)

That should give you a strong overview on how to properly build the database side. As for connecting it to your ASP.Net application, might I suggest the following article:

[Data Access Layer using Table Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx)

Hope this all helps a little. Good luck!